# cachespec.xml for object array in websphere cache

Tags: java, caching, websphere, websphere-8

Does anyone know how to configure cachespec for array values?

Has anyone come across such a requirement? Or if you have any ideas on configuring multiple name and values pairs in cachespec.xml please respond to me.

I tried

It is not able to identify the multiple values.

Comment: "I tried" -> what did you try?

Comment: <cache-id>
<component id="" type="serviceOperation">
<value>http://cds.dcl.mysis.com:getAsset</value>;
<required>true</required>
</component>
<component id="id" type="serviceOperationParameter"/>
<component id="realm" type="serviceOperationParameter"/>
<component id="securityId" type="serviceOperationParameter"/>
<timeout>86400</timeout>
</cache-id>

I was able to configure for id, realm, abd securityID. But when I try to configure for userproperties, where I have multiple name and values I was not able to cache the content.

Comment: Here is my SOAP Request content.

<appContext>
<id>ABB</id>
<realm />
<securityId>ECM1254789657841</securityId>
</appContext>
<userContext>
<userProperties>
<UserProperty>
<name>Language</name>
<value>ES</value>
<name>Language</name>
<value>KA</value>
</UserProperty>
</userProperties>
</userContext>

Comment: Please post this info in you question in code blocks for legibility - thanks!